# Built-in function IIF

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've been requested to migrate a project made with VBA in an Access DB to VB.Net with SQL Server 2008 R2. I've read in other threads that the function IIF does not come as a built-in function in such SQL Server version, creating it won't help it too, because the '=' operator can't be used to express a boolean in the first argument, and the problem using CASE is that some IIF's comes with more than one expression to evaluate inside.

In short words, this produces an error, "the = operator is not defined"

```
Iif(Value1 = Value2, 'Some return', 'Another return')
```

And an IIF expression like the following can't be translated to a CASE expression.

```
Iif((Value1 = Value2) And (Value3 = Value4), 'Value to return if true', 'Value to return if false')
```

I'm currently creating stored procedures and taking advantage of programming structures to overcome this problem, but it seems an inefficient workaround since there are lots of nested IIF's.

My question is, is there a more efficient way to do it?, or should i stick doing it with stored procedures?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every IIF can be translated to CASE. `Iif((Value1 = Value2) And (Value3 = Value4), 'Value to return if true', 'Value to return if false')` is equal to `case when Value1 = Value2 And Value3 = Value4 then 'Value to return if true' else 'Value to return if false' end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your `IIF` calls *can* be converted to `CASE` expressions:

```
IIF(Value1 = Value2, 'Some return', 'Another return')
IIF((Value1 = Value2) AND (Value3 = Value4), 'Value to return if true', 'Value to return if false')
```

can be rewritten as

```
CASE WHEN Value1 = Value2 THEN 'Some return' ELSE 'Another return' END
```

and

```
CASE WHEN (Value1 = Value2) AND (Value3 = Value4)
     THEN 'Value to return if true'
     ELSE 'Value to return if false'
END
```

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right, i don't know why it did not work when i tried, thank you. I will accept this answer as correct in 5 minutes more, since the page does not allow me to do it now.

Comment: Now i understand why it didn't work, and i think it's important to note that the boolean expression is in the WHEN clause and the CASE is empty, i was trying, following intuition only, to do Case <Expression> When <true> which is wrong and it is why it did not work in my first attempt. Thanks again, i leave this comment just if someone runs into a similar reasoning later.